# Macbook Pro Late 2013 with Intel Iris Pro only and BENQ BL2711U - how to connect

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a problem with connecting Macbook Pro 15' Retina (late 2013 with only Iris pro) with external monitor BENQ BL2711U. In specifications for MBP late 2013 with only Iris pro, HDMI supporting 3840x2160. Today I'm trying with BENQ BL2711U and nothing. No detected display on MBP , no signal on the monitor. How to connect this monitor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you connecting now?  HDMI?  DisplayPort?  What adapter (if any) are you using?

Comment: Through the HDMI port on MBP with HDMI cable to the monitor. No adapter or something else.

Comment: Are you certain that the monitor is functional?  If so, how did you confirm?  Is your HDMI port on the MBP functional?  Again, if so, how did you confirm?

Comment: At least , the HDMI port on the MBP doesn't work, no signal. This is very strange, because it has never been used before.